# Trying to fit a table in the width of a paper

Tags: tables

I am trying to make the width of the table equal or less than the width of the paper so it will fit in it. I wrote the code of the table below but it doesn't fit in the paper as shown in the figure below, any help??

[image]

My code is:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
                                & \textbf{k-generated} & \textbf{generated goal} & \textbf{male} & \textbf{female} \\
\textbf{NONgenerated}          & NO               & YES                     & YES          & NO             \\
\textbf{AUTOMATIC/generated supervising} & NO               & YES                     & YES          & YES            \\
\textbf{REAL-TIME/generated}       & NO               & NO                      & NO           & YES            \\
\textbf{generated}               & NO               & NO                      & NO           & YES            \\
\textbf{generated LOW}           & 0.9              & 0.74                    & 0.85         & 0.74           \\
\textbf{generated}             & LOW              & HIGH                    & HIGH         & LOW           
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please always post a complete small document don't make people  type the preamble in particlular the answer will be different of you want to fit A4 or US letter or two column or ...

Comment: So you're not concerned about the text block margins? That is, you just want the table to be placed in the (horizontal) centre of the page?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited the question .

Comment: @Werner I need the best way that I can put that table in the page.

Comment: I see no edit shown on the site? The code fragment should always start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: I thought u r talking about the page .. The problem it is multifiles but this is the beginning of the document \documentclass[12pt]{report}

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/1090

Comment: What does the first column represent? There are two **generated** entries, with different values in the other columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without resizing, you can use the `makecell` package and rotate the column heads:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{array, makecell, booktabs, rotating}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}

    \begin{document}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{table}[h]
  \renewcommand\cellrotangle{35}
  \settowidth{\rotheadsize}{ HIGH }
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{5}{l}@{}}
    \addlinespace[2ex]
                          & \rothead{\rlap{k-generated}} & \rothead{\rlap{generated goal}} & \rothead{\rlap{male}} & \rothead{\rlap{female}} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \thead{NONgenerated} & NO & YES & YES & NO \\
    \thead{AUTOMATIC/ & & & & \\generated supervising} & NO & YES & YES & YES \\
    \thead{REAL-TIME/ & & & & \\generated} & NO & NO & NO & YES \\
    \thead{generated} & NO & NO & NO & YES \\
    \thead{generated LOW} & 0.9 & 0.74 & 0.85 & 0.74 \\
    \thead{generated} & LOW & HIGH & HIGH & LOW \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is my approach, by order of preference, without decreasing the font size, totating or scaling text:

1. **Remove unnecessary words** or change by shorter words or redesign the table. This is not  showed in my MWE, because I do not understand the meaning of the example table, but probably all/most the words "generated" can be deleted without lost any meaning.
2. **Avoid all-caps words** except absolutely necessary for three reasons: (1) Need much more space (2) There are a general consensus that lower-case text is more legible. (3) Mixed upper-case and lower-case text is even worse. Look ugly, IMHO.
3. **Avoid bold fonts**. Bold fonts are bigger, but one or two horizontal rules is enough emphasis for the headers.
4. When is unavoidable that some cells must have too much text,  **use `tabulary`** or `tabularx` environments with the  packages of the same name to stay within the text width and/or use some like `p{3cm}` instead of `l`,`c` or `r` columns  to allow multi line cells (you can use this also in `tabular`). The length of p columns could be also a relative lenght as `.5\linewidth`.

In my example there are only two cells that need two lines. Not very nice. So think again in re-design the table. May be you can use "Goal" instead of "Generated goal" and only "Automatic/supervised" under a  "Generated" header in order to use only one row cells.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LcCcc}
\toprule                         & k-generated  & Generated Goal  & Male        & Female\\\midrule
Non generated                   & No           & Yes     & Yes          & No\\
Automatic/generated supervising & No           & Yes     & Yes          & Yes\\
Real-time/generated             & No           & No      & No           & Yes\\
Generated                       & No           & No      & No           & Yes\\
Generated low                   & 0.9          & 0.74    & 0.85         & 0.74\\
Generated                       & Low          & High    & High         & Low\\\bottomrule     
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Important note:** resizing components doesn't look very nice. Consider revising the table itself to fit fully-scaled in the page, or possibly changing the font size to `\small` or whatever's appropriate.

---

If you're just concerned with resizing the table to fit within the width of the page, the `graphicx` package provides `\resizebox`, which will do the trick. Using your table as an example:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Put in your document's preamble
\begin{table}[h]
  \resizebox{\hsize}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
      & \textbf{k-generated} & \textbf{generated goal} & \textbf{male} & \textbf{female} \\
      \textbf{NONgenerated}          & NO               & YES                     & YES          & NO             \\
      \textbf{AUTOMATIC/generated supervising} & NO               & YES                     & YES          & YES            \\
      \textbf{REAL-TIME/generated}       & NO               & NO                      & NO           & YES            \\
      \textbf{generated}               & NO               & NO                      & NO           & YES            \\
      \textbf{generated LOW}           & 0.9              & 0.74                    & 0.85         & 0.74           \\
      \textbf{generated}             & LOW              & HIGH                    & HIGH         & LOW           
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}
```

The first argument to `\resizebox` is the width of the resize box -- in this example, the horizontal size of its container. The second argument is the height, but `{!}` here just signals it to automatically compute the height to maintain aspect ratio. And the third argument is, of course, the content of the box.

That being said, I must reiterate: This won't look good. Change the table instead.

Comment: Where is my "please, do not do this" banner?! Seriously, **never do this, please.** The result is very likely to be completely unreadable, and also, a typographic disaster.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's true. Edited to emphasize that this isn't the best solution. It is the answer to the question though.

Comment: It is not 'the answer to the question'. At most, it is *an* answer to the question. I mention this only because it is, as you say yourself, not at all a good solution. So it really matters that it is not the only one!